# Type annotation for any collection of a particular type

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

Is there a type annotation to specify "any collection or generator whose items are of a given type" using Python's type annotation system?

I have a function that doesn't care if it gets a `list` or `tuple` `set` or `generator` or whatever, as long as it is a collection of instances of  a particular class.

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "collection"? Do you just want `typing.Iterable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combining feature of ordered, unordered and lazy collections is that they are [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Iterable). As such, an arbitrary "collection of `T`s" should be annotated as an `Iterable[T]`.